# How to run two parallel requests and join result in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, parallel-processing

I have the following code:

```
def do_smth(query):
    result_1 = api_request_1(query) # ['1', '2', '3']
    result_2 = api_request_2(query) # ['a', 'b', 'c']
    return result_1 + result_2      # ['1', '2', '3', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

Now I want to run these requests in parallel and combine the result. So I do:

```
def do_smth_parallel(query):
    pool = Pool(processes=2)

    result = []
    arg = [ query ]
    result.extend(pool.map(api_request_1, arg)[0])
    result.extend(pool.map(api_request_2, arg)[0])

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    return result
```

So far so good but `map` is a **blocking** function. So... `do_smth_parallel` isn't much `parallel` :)
How can I do that?

P.S. in Java I would use an `ExecutorService` and a couple of `Future`s to achieve that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way of doing this is with the `concurrent.futures` package:

```
from concurrent.futures import Executor

def do_smth_parallel(query):
    exc = Executor()

    req1 = exc.submit(api_request_1, query)
    req2 = exc.submit(api_request_2, query)

    return req1.result() + req2.result()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `map_async` https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult instead of `map`. Here is your adapted example. This can be applied to an arbitrary number of function calls. All will be execute asynchronously.

```
def do_smth_parallel(query):
    pool = Pool(processes=2)

    result = []
    arg = [ query ]
    future_1 = pool.async_map(api_request_1, arg)
    future_2 = pool.async_map(api_request_2, arg)

    result_1 = future_1.get()
    results_2 = future_2.get()

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    return result_1 + result_2
```

Comment: Thank you. That solves the problem but @Turn's way is more high level imho